# Borders for Divs - GRID in Media query

Tags: html, for-loop, grid, border, s

I have 2 questions about borders in a GRID.

1. Is there a better way other then what I am using for the page when viewed on a desktop monitor?
2. How to have no gap and a 2px border when viewed on a cell phone?
   See 9 div GRID. When using 2px in the media query it shows to thick.

View the css of the .div1, .div2 etc showing the border code.
I did not want to use in a media query.

Borders for Divs - GRID
https://codepen.io/davidhelp/pen/NWJoJaE?editors=1100

See css code for desktop view and media query. You can move the slider at codepen to see the media query view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--need this or some characters will display random gibberish -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- keeps text the size you want in cell phone screens. Without it the text will be very small. -->
  <title>Borders for Divs - GRID</title>

  <style>
   * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   body {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #2f97ff; /* background color */
   }

   .container {
    display: grid;
    width: 70%;
    grid-template-areas:
     "div1 div2 div3"
     "div4 div5 div6"
     "div7 div8 div9";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* .75 or .5 etc. only or combo, if px used for all then the container does not wrap around tightly */
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: #148aff;
    gap: 0px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
   }

   .container > div {
    place-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div1 {
    grid-area: div1;
    display: grid;
    background: #84d7ba;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div2 {
    grid-area: div2;
    display: grid;
    background: #50a7ff;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div3 {
    grid-area: div3;
    display: grid;
    background: #00c7a6;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div4 {
    grid-area: div4;
    display: grid;
    background: #fffee1;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div5 {
    grid-area: div5;
    display: grid;
    background: #148aff;
   }

   .div6 {
    grid-area: div6;
    display: grid;
    background: #ff8b61;
   }

   .div7 {
    grid-area: div7;
    display: grid;
    background: #5c5cdb;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
   }

   .div8 {
    grid-area: div8;
    display: grid;
    background: #d63f15;
   }

   .div9 {
    grid-area: div9;
    display: grid;
    background: #ae3fd6;
   }

   p {
    font-family: verdana, Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
   }

   h2 {
    font-family: "Bookman Old Style", serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
   }

   a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
   } /* black */
   a:active {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
   } /* red */
   a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
   } /* blue */
   a:hover {
    color: #ff8040;
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.02px red;
    background-color: #ffffff;
   }
   /* red bold shadow shift fix, white on mouse hover*/

   @media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    .container {
     grid-template-areas:
      "div1"
      "div2"
      "div3"
      "div4"
      "div5"
      "div6"
      "div7"
      "div8"
      "div9";
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: auto;
     width: 98%;
     height: 100vh;
     overflow-wrap: break-word;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     gap: 5px;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     background-color: #148aff;
    }

    .container > div {
     border: 2px solid #000000;
    }
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="div1"><p>div1</p></div>
   <div class="div2"><p>div2</p></div>
   <div class="div3"><p>div3</p></div>
   <div class="div4"><p>div4</p></div>
   <div class="div5"><p>div5</p></div>
   <div class="div6"><p>div6</p></div>
   <div class="div7"><p>div7</p></div>
   <div class="div8"><p>div8</p></div>
   <div class="div9"><p>div9</p></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #2f97ff;  /* background color */
}

.container {
  width: 90vw;
  background: #148AFF;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-group{
  display:flex;
  justifu-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  min-height:30vh;
}

.div1 {
  background: #84d7ba;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  background: #50A7FF;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.div3 {
  background: #00C7A6;
}

.middle-div{
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana, Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


a:link {color: #000000; text-decoration: underline; }  /* black */
a:active {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline; }  /* red */
a:visited {color: #000000; text-decoration: underline; }  /* blue */
a:hover { color: #ff8040; font-size:110%; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 0 0.02px red; background-color: #ffffff; }
/* red bold shadow shift fix, white on mouse hover*/

@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .flex-group{
    display:block;
  }

  .div{
    border:0; 
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
  }
  
  #last-div{
    border-bottom:0;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-group">
    <div class="div div1"><p>div1</p></div>
    <div class="div div2"><p>div2</p></div>
    <div class="div div3"><p>div3</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-group">
    <div class="div div1 middle-div"><p>div4</p></div>
    <div class="div div2 middle-div"><p>div5</p></div>
    <div class="div div3 middle-div"><p>div6</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-group">
    <div class="div div1"><p>div7</p></div>
    <div class="div div2"><p>div8</p></div>
    <div class="div div3"><p>div9</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bu not quite  : )  The lines are doubled up. Maybe I could add a div container and have a black background then add a gap. This for the media query and the desktop view. I will try that and update.

Comment: See codepen update. Also view in a web browser as the codepen is leaving out the outside border where as the web browser is showing them. The lines look equal for the desktop and cell phone views.

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean, wat do you wanna do?

Comment: See the codepen link. It is now fixed.

Comment: oh you don't want the border? just take it off.It' isn't that big of a deal

Comment: I edited my answer you can change sizes and colors as you wish